# JCL/REXX - Members in a PDS

Tags: jcl, rexx, clist

How can I create a member in a PDS using either JCL or REXX? The member's name must contain the actual date. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can be done in JCL and by Rexx. You need to remember that member names are a maximum of 8 bytes and cannot start with a numeric so you would need to use something like the 'Julian' date e.g. 2017365. You may have system variables available to populate your JCL - check the JCL manual and level of Z/os that you are using.